# android app can't find string resource at runtime

Tags: android

I have packed my AndroidStudio project in ubuntu14.04 which can be deployed on my cell phone properly.But when I unpacked it and tried to build and debug it in the windows10 AndroidStudio enveriment,I got this runtime error found in log:

```
    2018-11-28 17:15:16.071 21275-21303/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0d001f (t=12 e=31) (error -2147483647)
    2018-11-28 17:15:16.071 1697-1721/? I/zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10177 pid 16739 in 8ms
    2018-11-28 17:15:16.071 21275-21303/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f0d001f in package graduationproject.usst.edu.facedetect
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d001f
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:380)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1890)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:138)
    at com.nearme.statistics.rom.a.h.l.a(Utils.java:88)
    at com.nearme.statistics.rom.usermodel.a.c(BackgroundAppData.java:95)
    at com.nearme.statistics.rom.usermodel.a.a(BackgroundAppData.java:69)
    at com.nearme.statistics.rom.usermodel.a.a(BackgroundAppData.java:20)
    at com.nearme.statistics.rom.usermodel.BackgroundAppData$1$1.run(BackgroundAppData.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And I didn't have any error message in the debug toolbar:

```
    Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

I have checked my R.java class and I found：

```
    public static final int app_name=0x7f0d001f;
```

All where I used app_name is only in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="graduationproject.usst.edu.facedetect">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>


<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I think I am quiet sure this is where the problem occurs because when i changed

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

to

```
android:label="@string/another_name"
```

Then the error message in the log became:

```
2018-11-28 17:15:16.071 21275-21303/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f0d001e in package graduationproject.usst.edu.facedetect
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d001e
```

with the following in the R.java class:

```
public static final int another_name=0x7f0d001e;
```

The file "project\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml" exists and the body in it is:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">facedetect</string>

    <string name="another_name">facedetectt</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

The AndroidStudio version is 3.2.1 and I'm using

```
JDK 1.8
Android SDK 27
NDK 18
Gradle 4.6
Gradle plugin:3.2.1
```

I have tried rebuild,clean and I had even delete the Build folder to clean and rebuild thoroughly.

I don't know where the problems is. Can Anyone please kindly help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: did you have multi string.xml ?

Comment: No. only one string.xml

Comment: maybe try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart?

Comment: thanks but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; try disabling the "Instant Run" feature within Android Studio: **Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Instant Run** > uncheck **Enable Instant Run**.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043188/1992342