# Getting error on Android Run : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058

Tags: android

I'm getting error as following, it was working fine before:

```
2019-01-04 22:17:32.516 12750-12750/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-01-04 22:17:32.584 12750-12750/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f0e001e in package com.kushal.boulders
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e001e
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1709)
        at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:135)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2874)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-01-04 22:17:32.608 12750-12750/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2019-01-04 22:17:32.611 12750-12750/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kushal.boulders, PID: 12750
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kushal.boulders/com.kushal.boulders.activities.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:753)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
        at com.kushal.boulders.activities.AuthenticatedActivity.onCreate(AuthenticatedActivity.java:20)
        at com.kushal.boulders.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-01-04 22:17:32.616 1589-1646/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.kushal.boulders/.activities.SplashActivity
2019-01-04 22:17:32.617 1589-1646/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
**2019-01-04 22:17:32.619 1589-1646/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f0e001e in package com.kushal.boulders**
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e001e
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1709)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:223)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadSafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:242)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:197)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1763)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateUsageStats(ActivityManagerService.java:5012)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1506)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3875)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3817)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopCrashedActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3700)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopCrashedActivitiesLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2294)
        at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:747)
        at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:579)
        at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:447)
        at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:392)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:16212)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerService.java:16178)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:116)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3517)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
2019-01-04 22:17:32.619 1010-1155/? W/statsd: not interested in atom 130601
```

Comment: Could you ensure all the strings you use in your XMLs refer to an existing entry in `strings.xml`? Check it by cleaning & rebuilding the whole project

Comment: @ArthurAttout: Hi Just disabled Instant Run, and \\everything started working again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the Resolution:**

I disabled Instant Run from
 **Settings** → **Build, Execution, Deployment** → **Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run** (Just uncheck the box)

Comment: I have filed an Android Studio bug report for this; here is link if anyone wants to 'star' this issue to help draw attention to it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132686253