# PackageManager exception when string resource used as Android application label

Tags: android

I am suddenly seeing an exception being thrown at install time when I use a string resource (`@string/my_app_name`) in  `android:label` under the `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml. The exception is only thrown when the app is installed or updated. `my_app_name` is used elsewhere in the app without any errors.

My xml files have not been changed recently, but this exception only started appearing relatively recently. It is likely tied to an Android Studio, Gradle, or API update but I am not certain which specific update this exception started appearing with. I am running the most recent stable versions of everything (Android Studio 3.4, Gradle 5.1.1, targeting Android API 28). Restarting Android Studio, cleaning, rebuilding, purging cache, etc. have not helped.

I am certain it is the label attribute, as that is the string referenced, and if I change `android:label` from `@string/my_app_name` to hardcoded text, the exception disappears. What am I doing wrong?

**AndroidManifest.xml (trimmed for brevity):**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="123"
    android:versionName="1.23"
    >

    ...permission-related things...

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/my_app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
        ...activity-related things...
        </activity>

        <service
        ...service-related things...
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Strings.xml (trimmed for brevity):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_app_name">My App</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

**logcat output:**

```
2019-04-29 20:29:39.384 22487-22534/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f10002a in package com.mycompany.myapp
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f10002a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1678)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:204)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:194)
        at tvw.f(SourceFile:32)
        at tvw.c(SourceFile:1)
        at txt.c(SourceFile:7)
        at ude.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at ifd.run(Unknown Source:5)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Do you have another `strings.xml` file? I mean in localized `values` such as `values-fr`?

Comment: No.. only one strings.xml and no specific languages defined.

Comment: Try to change name of the string (for example set it to `app_name`) forcing the build process to assign new id in `R` class. Then set `translatable` attribute for it (`<string name="app_name" translatable="false">My App</string>`). Finally go to `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`. It may help you.

Comment: I had tried all of that except setting `translatable` so I gave it a shot.. same result. I hadn't touched this part of my project in years, I am wondering if there is some sort of obscure Gradle/Java/Android Studio bug causing it. I don't *need* to use a string reference here, but I want to know why it's happening.

Comment: just curious, what is the content of the string?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack I have tried many different strings, including "My App" -- all just plaintext standard English characters. The string was not changed for 4-5 years and the error suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this similar error after more research:

disable Instant Run from Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run (Just uncheck the box)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043052/getting-error-on-android-run-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! I have filed an Android Studio bug report; here is link if anyone wants to 'star' this issue to help draw attention to it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132686253

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I will use the `manifestPlaceholders` variable in my Gradle file:

```
 manifestPlaceholders = [appname: "My App"]
```

then in the manifest, do this:

```
android:label="${appname}"
```

This lets you have different app names for different build types (if you so choose)